# Dynamic properties in ruby class

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3

How can I create a dynamic property in ruby? This functionality exists in python.

```
class Example(object):
    value = "This is property!"

class Test(object):
    @property
    def check(self):
        return Example

test = Test()
print(test.check.value)  # This is property!
```

How can I do the same in ruby?

Comment: Ruby doesn't have properties. Can you clarify what you want your code to do? Preferably in a language that Rubyists can understand (i.e. Ruby), not every Rubyist is perfectly fluent in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Example
  def value
    "This is property!"
  end
end

class Test
  def check
    Example.new
  end
end

test = Test.new
puts test.check.value  # This is property!
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class Test
  def check
   "This is property!"
  end
end

test = Test.new
puts(test.check) # This is property!
```

Comment: I know about this solution. But it's a method, not a property. I can't do like that: `test.check.again`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want from your example. Properties (from what I've seen) are usually used to create setters and getters. You can have that in Ruby with `attr_accessor`:

```
class Test
  attr_accessor :check
end
```

You can call `attr_accessor` anytime you want an attribute:

```
class Test
  %w{this are possible attribute names}.each do |att|
    attr_accessor att
  end
end
```

Or

```
Class Test
end

test = Test.new
Test.send(:attr_accessor, :whatever)
test.whatever = "something"
test.whatever # => "something"
```

If you only want a getter you have `attr_reader`, and there's `attr_writer` for a writer. They all, for an attribute called `attribute_name`, use an instance variable called `@attribute_name`. They all may be built with `instance_variable_set` and `instance_variable_get`, which allow dynamically setting and getting instance variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ruby's `method_missing` to achieve something similar:

```
class TestCheck
  def method_missing(methodId)
    if(methodId.id2name == "check")
      puts "check called"
    else
      puts "method not found"
    end
  end

end

t = TestCheck.new
t.check      #=> "check called"
t.something_else   #=> "method not found"
```

Reference: [Ruby docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-method_missing)